# Select from SQL Server table where all records have a column value of a range specified

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this table :

```
create table Test
(
    Input_Id int,
    Id int,
    primary key (Input_Id ,Id)
)

insert into Test 
values (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 21), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 21), 
       (3, 244), (3, 246), (3, 248), (4, 2), (4, 4)
```

I want to run a select which will return only the Input_Id's where all of the Id's are in a range I am specifying e.g. if I pass a range of 2,4,244,246,21 I would expect just 3 to be returned.

So far I have

```
select Input_Id 
from Test 
where id in (2, 4, 244, 246, 21) 
group by Input_Id
```

But this is returning 2, 3 and 4 not just 3.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why Group By Input_id?

Comment: Consider Input_Id `5` has `2,4,244,246,21,99` now do you want 5 in result ? note, there is one extra value 99

Answer (score 3):

Your query returned the correct results because Input_Id 2, 3, and 4 are associated with Id's contained in your `IN` clause. You can see that by running this:

```
select * 
from Test 
where id in (2,4,244,246,21)
```

I think what you are looking for is to return all Input_Id which have ALL of the ID's in your `IN` clause, which would only be Input_Id = 3. In that case, you want to use `HAVING`. IN the below query I'm checking to make sure the Input_Id has all 5 of the items in your `IN` clause.

```
select Input_Id 
from Test 
where id in (2,4,244,246,21) 
group by Input_Id 
having count(distinct Id) = 5
```